# C++ Operator Overloading Int Types

Tags: c++, int, operator-overloading, fractions

I'm working on a fractions class in C++ and have defined the addition of a frac and an int in the new class, but it requires them to show up in that order: frac + int. Is there a way to overload + in the Int type such that we have a function that accepts a frac and outputs a frac? Or is there a way to reverse the order in the new class?

I already have frac + frac and frac += frac operators defined. The two functions in question are:

```
frac operator+=(int b)
{
    frac c = { n + b*d, d };
    return c;
}

frac operator+(int b)
{
    frac c = *this;
    frac d = { b };
    c += d;
    return c;
}
```

something like this:

```
frac int::operator+=(frac& b)
{
    frac c = { this * b.den() + b.num(), b.den() };
    return c;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to actually accomplish this.

---

Code from question below:

```
frac &operator+=(frac b)
{
    frac c = { n * b.den() + b.num() * d, d * b.den() };
    n = c.num();
    d = c.den();
    return *this;
}

frac operator+(int a, frac b)
{
    return frac{ a } += b;
}
```

Comment: First overthink your signatures. `frac &operator+=(int b)`, `frac operator+(int b)`

Comment: This is my ignorance talking, but what does making it return a reference actually change here? It was working with the code before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there's no class `int` so you can't do what you suggested but the easy thing is to declare a function like this (inside your class)

```
 friend frac operator+(int a, frac b);
```

That way this function will be called when the other order is used. Edit: you need to use the `friend`specifier because the function isn't in the class, I forgot about that.

Comment: When I do it this way I get the error "Error: too many parameters for this operator function".

Comment: this is a possible way, but it should NOT be inside the class

Comment: @BeaumontTaz Paste your code. You probably put something other than precisely what was suggested above.

Comment: Moving it from inside the class fixed the error. However, the solution by @Matt McNabb works for both directions.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is to make `frac` have an implicit constructor from int, and use a free `operator+` so that conversions apply to both arguments. Also you can implement `+` in terms of `+=` and so on. E.g.

```
struct frac
{
    frac(int x) { /* initialize frac with x */ }

    frac &operator+=(frac f) { /* add f to this */ return *this; }
};

frac operator+(frac f1, frac f2)
{
    return f1 += f2;
}
```

**Update**: some people consider implicit conversion constructors to be bad style; if you're one of those then you can work around it by using an explicit constructor and writing a series of operators with exact parameters, e.g.

```
frac operator+(int f1, frac f2) { return frac(f1) += f2; }
frac operator+(frac f1, int f2) { return f1 += frac(f2); }
frac operator+(frac f1, frac f2) { return f1 += f2; }
```

Comment: No, this is not the proper way.

Comment: Well even if this work in some times it doesn't make sense to convert, especially if you're talking about multiplication. If you make a class for time it makes sense to multiply with an int but not by 5 seconds (or if you do that you don't output a time. Converting can also waste time so it's rarely the most efficient.

Comment: I'd say an implicit conversion is almost never proper. Too dangerous. We can barely deal with the C legacy arithmetic promotions, adding more of the same to the mix is unwise.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the member operators as static and you can have two parameters. See the declaration of WholeNumber -- the operators are static and have no instance of *this.

[Operators in Cross Compiler Objects within Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553121/operators-in-cross-compiler-objects-within-visual-studio-solved-thanks-hans)